# Has my server been hacked?

Tags: linux

Recently my host (OVH) shut down my server due to it spamming traffic to another IP:

[image]

I've got no idea what the other IP is. It doesn't appear to be a web page (Or if it is, I can't connect to it).

Here is my latest authentication logs:
[image]

My current IP at the time of writing is 146.90.203.194.

Have I been hacked, or is there simply a piece of faulty software? If I've been hacked, what can I do about it?

By the way, I don't use any keys, I only use password authentication.

The server went down at approximately 11:30, which is the same time as the above displayed log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't been hacked, you've been DDoS.
Here's a (french) page about how to deal with DDoS attacks: https://www.ovh.com/fr/anti-ddos/gestion-attaque-ddos.xml
Some documentation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack

Also, you're bruteforced: a bot tries to find your password. Make sure your password is strong, you can also install fail2ban to ban bruteforcing IP.

Comment: My server is SENDING the DoS attack. Not receiving it. The IP starting with 91, specified as the source IP, is the IP of my server. Also, thanks for letting me know I'm not hacked.

Comment: Oh well I've misread, that change everything. So yes, wou could be hacked. Type "w" in a terminal to see who's connected and change all your passwords.

Comment: Could it also be a piece of malicious software? If so, is there any way for me to pinpoint it down?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know what a good backup could be. I run a minecraft server, and someone could have added a dormant exploit in there for months before using it, which is actually what most of them do to so that they get most infected servers.
There is simply no way of me knowing what backup is not infected, or if even ANY of the backups are not infected.

Comment: @Ramhound Is it not possible to one, block all outgoing connections initiated, and two, check the outgoing connections to see what application made them? Is that not possible?

Comment: Sure its possible to block the ip address of the current attack.  If your server is indeed compromised, and they have root access, they could just reverse your changes.  Honstly your security wasn't strong enough, you should have been using ssh keys, at least for root.

Comment: @Ramhound Root is disabled, and I have a 100-character-long password for my account. Is that not good enough?

Comment: My host is completely blocking me from using the server, and have not even replied in 3 days. I'm switching. Still, thank you for all the help.